# TreeNode name in C# CF

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode, windows-mobile-6.5, .net-cf-3.5

I'm building an application with the .NET Compact Framework v3.5 with C# using Visual Studio 2008. The OS is Windows Mobile 6.5.3

For listing articles I want to use a TreeView, but I can't figure out how to give the node its own identifier. This is how it'll be displayed:

> -Article 
>   ---Part 
>   ---Part 
>   -Article 
>   ---Part 
>   -Article 
>   ---Part 
>   ---Part

I've seen examples that set the name attribute of the treenode, but apparently that doesn't exist in this framework.

I also can't display the identifier in the value attribute, because it displays other information.

So my question is: how can I search for the right treenode in the treeview when using the identifier?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [TreeNode's Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to store/associate any information you would like about each node.

> **TreeNode.Tag Property**
>
> Gets or sets the object that contains data
> about the tree node.

When you search the tree you cast your object from the `Tag` property of the node and perform your business logic.

Comment: Thanks alot for you answer! I didn't know that the solution could be that simple.